# Scrape all images of off a multiple pages site?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

> I need to scrape all the images of the pages of the url given in the code but i could only do it manually each page till the last page(100th page).
>
> This is the code for scraping each page and i replace the page number each time and run the code!
>
> > Down below
>
> Is there any way to add a variable function and running a loop till it gets an error in this case a 404 page (since no more pages would be left)?

```
from bs4 import*
import requests as rq
r2 = rq.get("https://www.gettyimages.in/photos/aishwarya-rai?family=editorial&page=1&phrase=aishwarya%20rai&sort=mostpopular")

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, "html.parser") 

links = []

x = soup2.select('img[src^="https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/"]')  #the frame where it shows the images

for img in x:
    links.append(img['src'])


for index, img_link in enumerate(links):
      img_data = rq.get(img_link).content
      with open("aishwarya_rai/"+str(index+2)+'.jpg', 'wb+') as f:
           f.write(img_data)
else:
      f.close()
```

### The page ranges from 1 to 100.

### I need some additional code which makes the "page value" a variable and loops till 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `format()` function and pass the page variable.

```
from bs4 import*
import requests as rq

url="https://www.gettyimages.in/photos/aishwarya-rai?family=editorial&page={}&phrase=aishwarya%20rai&sort=mostpopular"

links = []
for page in range(1,101):
    print(url.format(page))
    r2 = rq.get(url.format(page))
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, "html.parser")
    x = soup2.select('img[src^="https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/"]')  
    for img in x:
      links.append(img['src'])

print(links)
```